# How to subsample a dataframe based on individual ID's and time

Tags: r, datetime, subset, telemetry

I have over 113,000 acoustic telemetry data points and I want to randomly subset one data point every hour for each unique animal ID. The thing is, not every animal ID will be present in every hour. Is there a way to subset my data in R even though not every animal ID is present in every hour?

Here is a snapshot of the data:

```
data_hour          transmitter_id            DATETIME
1 2021-10-15 19:00          64617 2021-10-15 19:06:11
2 2021-10-15 19:00          64599 2021-10-15 19:07:08
3 2021-10-15 19:00          64599 2021-10-15 19:12:10
4 2021-10-15 19:00          64621 2021-10-15 19:16:29
5 2021-10-15 19:00          64599 2021-10-15 19:20:09
6 2021-10-15 19:00          64599 2021-10-15 19:21:47
....
35 2021-10-15 19:00         64621 2021-10-15 19:58:09
36 2021-10-15 19:00         64617 2021-10-15 19:58:44
37 2021-10-15 19:00         64599 2021-10-15 19:59:41
38 2021-10-15 20:00         64599 2021-10-15 20:02:16
39 2021-10-15 20:00         64599 2021-10-15 20:04:20
40 2021-10-15 20:00         64617 2021-10-15 20:04:29
41 2021-10-15 20:00         64621 2021-10-15 20:05:15
42 2021-10-15 20:00         64617 2021-10-15 20:07:01
43 2021-10-15 20:00         64599 2021-10-15 20:07:25
44 2021-10-15 20:00         64603 2021-10-15 20:09:11

...etc.
```

Thank you very much for any help/suggestions, R newbie!

Answer (score 2):

**Update** thanks to @Arthur: See comments:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(data_hour, transmitter_id) %>% 
  slice_sample(n=1)

 data_hour        transmitter_id DATETIME           
  <chr>                     <int> <chr>              
1 2021-10-15 19:00          64599 2021-10-15 19:21:47
2 2021-10-15 19:00          64617 2021-10-15 19:06:11
3 2021-10-15 19:00          64621 2021-10-15 19:58:09
4 2021-10-15 20:00          64599 2021-10-15 20:07:25
5 2021-10-15 20:00          64603 2021-10-15 20:09:11
6 2021-10-15 20:00          64617 2021-10-15 20:07:01
7 2021-10-15 20:00          64621 2021-10-15 20:05:15
```

We could group and use `slice_sample()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(data_hour) %>% 
  slice_sample(n=1)

  data_hour        transmitter_id DATETIME           
  <chr>                     <int> <chr>              
1 2021-10-15 19:00          64617 2021-10-15 19:06:11
2 2021-10-15 20:00          64599 2021-10-15 20:04:20
```

Comment: If I understand the OP question there has to be a sample per ID per HOUR. If we consider `transmitter_id` to be the animal identifier, it should be used in the group_by as well, as `group_by(data_hour, transmitter_id)`

Comment: Hi thank you! This looks like it chooses one transmitter_id for each hour. I would like to have one sample taken for each transmitter_id present in each hour (if it/they are present). So, there would be multiple 2021-10-15 entries, all with a unique transmitter_id. Thanks @Arthur, exactly! Thank you I will try adding that!

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: It worked beautifully thanks so much!